# instead of change select tag javascript insert template's dynamic select

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, html-select

I am trying to create dynamic select, it started to work in some strange way. instead of new options for select tag, javascript inserts content of template's html

index.html.erb

```
   <%= collection_select(nil, :site_id,  @sites,  :id, :name, {:prompt   => "Select a Site"}, { :id => "sites_select"}) %>
                                <br/>
                        <%= collection_select(nil, :floor_id, @floors, :id, :name, {:prompt   => "Select a Floor"}, {:id => "floors_select"}) %>
                        <br/>
                        <%= collection_select(nil, :pod_id, @pods, :id, :name, {:prompt   => "Select a pod"}, {:id => "pods_select"}) %>
                        <script>
                              $(document).ready(function() {
                               $("#sites_select").change(function(){
                                        $.ajax({
                                          url: "#{update_floors_path}",
                                          //orther options ...
                                          success: function(data){
                                              site_id : $('#sites_select').val()
                                              $("#floors_select").html(data);
                                          }
                                        });

                                    });
                                $("#floors_select").change(function(){
                                        $.ajax({
                                          url: "#{update_pods_path}",
                                          //orther options ...
                                          success: function(data){
                                              floor_id : $('#floors_select').val()
                                              $("#pods_select").html(data);
                                          }
                                        });

                                    });

                              });
                            </script>
```

source:

```
   <select id="floors_select" name="[floor_id]">


   <title>ELS Reservation Tool</title>
  <link href="/assets/style.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

 <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param">
<meta content="3F+WpxiRZx+7u9POFOgeRHZ0QlhMrs3ccLnvUgjodio=" name="csrf-token"> etc...
```

devices_controller.rb

```
 #for dynamic select
   def update_floors
    # updates floors and pods based on genre selected
    site = Site.find(params[:site_id])
    # map to name and id for use in our options_for_select
    @floors = site.floors.map{|a| [a.name, a.id]}.insert(0, "Select a Floor")
    @pods   = site.pods.map{|s| [s.name, s.id]}.insert(0, "Select a Pod")

    respond_to do |format|
         format.js
        end 
  end

   def update_pods
    # updates pods based on floor selected
    floor = Floor.find(params[:floor_id])
    @pods =floor.pods.map{|s| [s.name, s.id]}.insert(0, "Select a Pod")

        respond_to do |format|
             format.js
            end 
  end




    <title>ELS Reservation Tool</title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10000; URL=http://els-hq-reserve:3000/">
    <link href="/assets/style.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">













    <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param">
    <meta content="3F+WpxiRZx+7u9POFOgeRHZ0QlhMrs3ccLnvUgjodio=" name="csrf-token">


    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->





    <div id="header">
      <img src="/images/elspmrt.png">     
    </div>
    <div id="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Saved Views</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Power Group</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Reserved</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
      <div id="content-container1">


    <div id="content">
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Search</h2>

              <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/devices" method="get"><div         style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"></div>
              <label for="label">Super Search:</label>
                    <input id="superstring" name="superstring" type="text">




              <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Search">

</form>
```

routes.rb

```
 get 'devices/update_floors', :as => 'update_floors'
      get 'devices/update_pods', :as => 'update_pods'
      root :to => "devices#index"
```

update_floors.js.erb

```
# app/views/devices/update_floors.js.erb
$('#floors_select').html("#{escape_javascript(options_for_select(@floors))}");
$('#pods_select').html("#{escape_javascript(options_for_select(@pods))}");
```

update_pods.js.erb

```
# app/views/home/update_pods.js.erb
$('#pods_select').html("<%= escape_javascript(options_for_select(@pods)) %>");
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you, D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues I see with your code, I dont know if you were changing the actual code you have to edit for the sake of giving an example, but its confusing, for example,

```
url: "#{update_pods_path}",
```

Shouldnt be working as it doesen't appear to be within a ruby block , you should be doing

```
url: "<%= update_pods_path %>",
```

unless there is something I'm missing. Anyways, all the other possible problems aside:

The answer to the root problem, is you are requesting the wrong url. When you do:

```
$.ajax({
```

In jquery, it is just doing a get request to the url path you pass. You need to specify that it is a JS request in jQuery, via the following:

```
$.getScript(url, function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {

});
```

Furthermore, unless you are requesting JSON, or you actually want raw html (only if you are rending an html partial directly from the controller), you shouldn't be doing anything with the response, the JS response should be replacing or updating the view directly. It just returns the javascript within the myresponse.js.erb file directly, and then executes it on the page. -- The following should be all you need:

```
$.getScript(url);
```

Your JS response should be making the changes to your page. It looks like your

```
update_pods.js.erb
$('#pods_select').html("<%= escape_javascript(options_for_select(@pods)) %>");
```

is written correctly, the floors one will need to be updated to match the latter.

Comment: Thank you , I am doing something from the begiinning..,